# How to access external live meeting url via HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to access external live meeting url using Httpwebrequest, and getting 401 unauthorized error. Same code is working in my local system.

Code:

```
     HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PostingUrl);
     CredentialCache CredMCCache = new CredentialCache();
        myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
        CredMCCache.Add(new System.Uri(PostingUrl),"Basic",new    System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
 myReq.Credentials = CredMCCache;
        myReq.KeepAlive = true;
        myReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)";
        myReq.Accept = "*/*";
        myReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us");
        myReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("proxy url with port", false);
        myReq.Proxy = proxyObject;
        myReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        myReq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse myResp = null;


            // Get the response from the conference center
            myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
```

I am getting the error in the above line. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the proxy, eg

> myReq.Proxy = proxyObject;

Do you need to do this? if you are indeed going thru a corporate proxy you shouldnt need to set the proxy for the `HttpWebRequest` as it will be pick up the settings (if any) from IE.

Secondly, are you trying to use basic authentication to authenticate with the remote server? It looks like you are, so use this instead to set the authenitcation details in the header

```
string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
myReq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
```